# Steam Web API GetCollectionDetails not working

Tags: steam-web-api, garrys-mod

I'm attempting to output a list of addons from a steam workshop collection. Every time I do so, it does not work. Here is the api link I am using.

Link: https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamRemoteStorage/GetCollectionDetails/v0001/?publishedfileids=532551393&format=json

Keep in mind, I'm using this application on the google chrome store called "Postman" to post the api, but always resulting in this error message.

---

Bad Request

### Please verify that all required parameters are being sent

Comment: did you verified that all required parameters are beign sent?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `collectioncount` POST parameter.

Refer to this site to test your API requests to Steam, helps a lot. https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html

[image: Submitting request through POSTMAN]

Comment: @XQuantumForceX updated my answer. It has to be a POST request as well. Input the credentials into that site and you will see that it works. Problem is probably how you send the request.